# Set focus of text box in directive

Tags: angularjs

I'm experimenting with an inline-edit directive form here: http://icelab.com.au/articles/levelling-up-with-angularjs-building-a-reusable-click-to-edit-directive/

**I would like to know how to set the cursor in the text box that gets created when I click some text to be edited.**

Here is the directive with a few minor changes to the template:

```
.directive("clickToEdit", function() {
    var editorTemplate = '<div class="click-to-edit">' +
        '<div ng-hide="view.editorEnabled" ng-click="enableEditor()">' +
            '{{value}} ' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div ng-show="view.editorEnabled">' +
            '<input ng-model="view.editableValue" ng-blur="save()">' +
        '</div>' +
    '</div>';

    return {
        restrict: "A",
        replace: true,
        template: editorTemplate,
        scope: {
            value: "=clickToEdit",
        },
        controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.view = {
                editableValue: $scope.value,
                editorEnabled: false
            };

            $scope.enableEditor = function() {
                $scope.view.editorEnabled = true;
                $scope.view.editableValue = $scope.value;
            };

            $scope.disableEditor = function() {
                $scope.view.editorEnabled = false;
            };

            $scope.save = function() {
                $scope.value = $scope.view.editableValue;
                $scope.disableEditor();
            };
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: HTML 5 attribute `autofoucs`?

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a link function like this :

```
link : function(scope, ele, attrs) {
      scope.$watch('view.editorEnabled', function(n, o) {
          if(n) ele.find('input')[0].focus();

      })
}
```